# Pandas - How to create a new column depending on logic between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the price of energy in a country by days, the price at which the energy is buyed depends in the offer of energy, i.e if there is a low offer price will increase and viceversa. To avoid the collapse of the energy stock market the government defined some values called activation prices that are calculated with the average of energy that the country has produced in the last days, if the energy stock market price go over this activation prices the price at which the energy is buyed is defined by a price called shortage price which mean that the offer is really low. I need to create a pandas columns that has the real price at which the energy is being sold, that means check if the energy stock market price of the energy is above the activation price to set the price to shortage price or if the price is bellow the activation price, the real price will be the energy stock market.
the pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
Fecha    Precio máximo de Bolsa ($/kWh)     Precio de escasez ($/kWh)   Precio marginal de escasez ($/kWh)  Precio de escasez de activación ($/kWh)
            
2020-01-01  406.73  551.24  627.21  627.21
2020-01-02  397.90  551.24  627.21  627.21
2020-01-03  285.31  551.24  627.21  627.21
2020-01-04  255.36  551.24  627.21  627.21
2020-01-05  305.12  551.24  627.21  627.21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Pandas' Series.Where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['real_price'] = df['stock_price'].where(df['stock_price'] <= activation_price, shortage_price)
```

This keeps the original value where the condition is `True`, and when it is `False` then it sets the value to the last argument.

Comment: it is like SQL?

Comment: Yes, very similar in the sense that `where` filters the table based on your condition, but the Pandas method has the added functionality of replacing values based on that filter. You can pass the output to a new column (as I did above) to avoid overwriting the original column.